# How is this declaring an object with a single named function parameter?

Tags: javascript

Declaration in question:

```
let foo = { bar () {} };
{ bar: [Function: bar] }
```

This creates an object with a single property `bar` that is an arrow function and assigns it to `foo`.
So `{ bar: () => {} }` is this `{ bar () {} }`?
Can someone explain/expand on this?
Anyone have a reference to documentation on this?
Is there a term for this kind of declaration (that I can Google)?
Other than saving some keystrokes, any reason to use this kind of declaration?

Comment: It's one of the shortcuts that was added in ES6.

Comment: Shorthand method definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#method_definitions `let foo = { bar () {} };` is short for `let foo = { bar: function () {} };`, not `let foo = { bar: () => {} };`

Comment: "*This creates an object with a single property bar that is an arrow function and assigns it to foo.*" it's **not** an arrow function. It's (almost entirely) a regular function. The only difference is that it's not constructable.

Comment: @jabaa Are you sure about `{ bar: function () {} }` ?  Try `let foo = { bar () {} }; let x = new foo.bar();`  You should get "TypeError: x.foo is not a constructor" which you only get with arrow functions, not normal functions.

Comment: "*which you only get with arrow functions*" and method definitions

Comment: That's what the documentation says. `bar () {}` is a shorthand for `bar: function () {}`

Comment: I guess also generator functions.

Comment: I should rtfm before commenting XP  Seems odd to have a "regular function" but not act as a regular function in that it's not constructable.  Thanks for all the replies and link to the documentation. I figured it was shorthand but didn't connect it to `let a = 'a'; let b = { a };` shorthand.

Comment: But it's not really related to `{ a }`. Well, the relation is that both are part of object initialiser syntax but by that definition `:` is also the same thing.  As for "*Seems odd to have a "regular function" but not act as a regular function in that it's not constructable*" it's exceptionally rare that a callable property of an object also needs to be usable as constructor. When defining actual methods, then in all sensible cases I can think of you'd *not* want them callable with `new`. As that's almost assuredly a mistake. And if it's not, it's not really a method you have.

Comment: It's almost like an "anonymous class object instance" declaration?  It behaves similarly.  `class Foo { bar() {} }` and `let foo = new Foo(); foo.bar(); /* fine */ new foo.bar(); /* TypeError: not a constructor */` Which feels like: `let foo = { bar () {} };`